# SQL Server CE error Access to the database file is not allowed

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf, sql-server

I have a WPF application and I'm using SQL Server CE on it. It works fine when debugging with Visual Studio, but when I install the application in any computer, an error message is shown saying:

> *Access to the database file is no allowed*

and the path of my database(usually the folder where the application was installed `C:/ProgramFiles`).

Comment: Never store user data in `C:/ProgramFiles`. Not only is it unwritable by Standard users, it gets deleted when you uninstall the app. Users don't like it when you delete all their data when they uninstall an app.

Answer (score 3):

The folders `C:\program files` or `C:\program files (x86)` cannot be used to store writable elements of an application like a database file. This is a security change made in Vista and in Win7 (UAC).

You should choose a different location (MyDocuments, ProgramData or else) where to store your database file during setup.

When you debug in Visual Studio, you are running your application inside the Solution Directory and subfolder bin\debug where you have read/write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the file is readonly, if it is readonly please uncheck before you open the same.